# Why is it always returning the first statement of the if/ifelse/else statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, random

```
<?php
     $type = rand(0,1).PHP_EOL;
     echo $type;
     if ($type == 0) {
          include_once 'include/types of lections/type1.php';
     } elseif ($type == 1) {
          include_once 'include/types of lections/type2.php';
     } else {
          include_once 'include/types of lections/type3.php';
     }
?>
```

I wanted to randomly include three different types of lections. With the code I'm using the echo $type; is random (0 or 1), but it includes always type1.php. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not always doing that: https://3v4l.org/ts9P8 . P.S. the last `else` is completely redundant, that case can never occur, given that you're only allowing two possible values (see the possible return values at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php). I don't think you've provided a [mre] of the issue, unfortunately. See also [ask].

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the help. I have tried to rerun the code and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of problems with your code:

**1.**`rand(0,1)` will always return either 0 or 1, so `$type` will always be either 0 or 1, and the else block will never be executed.

**2.** You are using `==` to compare `$type` to the integer values 0 and 1. This is not wrong, but it is more common to use `===` to compare both the value and the type of a variable. In this case, `$type` is a string because it is concatenated with PHP_EOL, so using `===` would make the comparison more accurate.

**3.** You are using `include_once` to include the files. This will include the file only if it has not been included before. If you want to include the file every time, you should use `include` instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the tips. But it should be random? It should include type1 or type2?